# Ios- is there a way to programmatically detect when someone presses a number on their dial pad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sdk

I am making an app that will act as an office phone. However is there a way to programmatically detect whether someone pressed "1" or "2" on the their dial pad and then send it back to me (who has the app) or send a voice recording of some kind. For example, if they press "1" it notifies me they want English and I can send them a voice recoding in English.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're talking about having your app get info about what the user does from the phone app, and the ability to inject sounds into the speaker?

No, Apple does not allow 3rd party apps to interact with the phone like this.

You could display a number pad inside your app and respond to taps when the user presses numbers in your app, but not during a phone call.

Comment: Ah okay thanks. I'm trying to make an app similar to Grasshopper which is used to transfer calls. How come they can detect when a user needs to be connected to someone else or do they integrate the app with an ip pbx?

Comment: I have no idea. It must do something like working with a PBX or controlling calls over VoIP. I would think you'd be able to tell that by setting up and using the app.